# SQL select from XML column with formatted output

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to select XML list values as comma separated and decorated with custom format(eg:x)

Input sample, it will have multiple rows

```
1 |    <User Name="AAA" /><User Name="BBB" />
2 |    <User Name="CCC" /><User Name="DD" />
```

Output Required

```
1 | xAAAx,xBBBx      
2 | xCCCx,xDDDx
```

My Progress

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT @xml = N'
<User Name="AAA"/>
<User Name="BBB"/>'

Declare @TempT TABLE (id int, data xml)

INSERT INTO @TempT VALUES (1,@xml)

set @xml  = N'
<User Name="CCC"/>
<User Name="DDD"/>'
INSERT INTO @TempT VALUES (2,@xml) 

SELECT * from @TempT

DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+', ' ,'') 
+ 'x'+T.C.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(50)') +'x' 
FROM @xml.nodes('User') T(C)
SELECT @listStr
```

Comment: Please add the name of database management tool to your question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: MSSQL server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @TempT table(data xml)

insert into @TempT (data) values
(N'<User Name="AAA"/><User Name="BBB"/><User Name="CCC"/>'),
(N'<User Name="CCC"/><User Name="DDD"/>');

select stuff((
             select ',x'+N.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(50)')+'x'
             from T.data.nodes('/User/@Name') as N(X)
             for xml path(''), type
             ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
from @TempT as T;
```

Result:

```
-------------------
xAAAx,xBBBx,xCCCx
xCCCx,xDDDx
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Declare @TempT TABLE (id int, data xml)
> insert into @TempT values (1, N'<User Name="AAA"/><User Name="BBB"/>');
> insert into @TempT values (2, N'<User Name="CCC"/><User Name="DDD"/>');
>
> SELECT * from @TempT;
>
> select 'x' + data.value('(User/@Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') + 'x,'
>        + 'x' + data.value('(User/@Name)[2]', 'varchar(50)') + 'x'
> from   @TempT 
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | data                                  
> -: | :-------------------------------------
>  1 | <User Name="AAA" /><User Name="BBB" />
>  2 | <User Name="CCC" /><User Name="DDD" />
>
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | xAAAx,xBBBx      |
> | xCCCx,xDDDx      |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c3ad46913fc6c35701cff32531526d5b)*

Comment: This query is not generic, because for every new record I need to edit select query

Comment: Isn't the two items by record? Please clarify the question by adding a real XML content.